# Timer function using Twilio functions

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions

Is it possible to create a timer that does callback after 5 minutes? In the documentation there seems to be a 5 second execution limit after which everything gets reset. Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio Functions have an execution limit of 5 seconds and do not offer a scheduler of any sort. There is no workaround short of using a different platform to schedule jobs.

Comment: How about a function that calls itself every 4 seconds?

Comment: That is not an idea that I would recommend.

Comment: How can one ask Twilio to provide such functionality? Since Twilio functions are using node.js which has non-blocking asynchronous timers: https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html
It would seem they wouldn't use much resources.

Comment: Functions do use Node, but they are built upon existing compute as a service platforms that have limits for how long a function can run and also charge by the time the function is in use (even if idle, waiting for something to happen). Twilio Functions is currently a simple way to run Node scripts in an environment managed by Twilio. If you need more than that then I recommend looking at the larger compute platforms offerings, like AWS, GCP or Azure, as they will be able to do this.

Comment: How about using: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/pause
Whats the maximum amount of seconds for the pause verb?

Comment: Using `<Pause>` inserts a pause into the flow of a call. You still have to return the TwiML within the 5 second time out of a Function though. A `<Pause>` does need to be less than the RTP timeout of 60 seconds and practically less than 50 seconds. `<Pause>` is not built for long pauses because that would be weird for the person on the other end of the phone.

Comment: Was thinking <Pause> on a third conference annoucer. But <Pause> pauses the whole conference?

Comment: No, `<Pause>` leaves a gap in the call for the caller on the other end of the call. It's for leaving gaps in messages like: `<Say>Hello</Say><Pause length="2"/><Say>How can I help today?</Say>`. If you're trying to use this to announce things to people in a conference after 5 minutes, it's not likely to work due to the RTP timeout I mention above.